# How to connect a Wii console to HDMI computer screen or through the computer itself?

Tags: display, hdmi, wii

I would like to play my Wii through my HDMI computer screen if it's possible. My BENQ G2420HD screen has got these inputs:

- HDMI
- DVI-D
- D-SUB

If it isn't possible to run it through the screen could you use the PC as a converter and then out to the HDMI input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to hook up the Wii console to the TV screen. That would basically mean your hooking Computer A to Computer connected by say HDMI. You would need to get a HDMI->DVI-D+Audio converter. In other words highly unlikely. The Wii does not support any of those 3 audio and/or video formats

Something like this would work: [http://www.amazon.com/HDMI-Composite-S-Video-Converter-3RCA/dp/B0047PDBP0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1326915664&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047PDBP0) or this: [http://www.amazon.com/HDMI-RCA-component-AV-Converter/dp/B002WBOQPU/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1326915783&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002WBOQPU)

These converters MIGHT NOT DO HDMI OUT.

Comment: If these converters do not support HDMI out then you are out of luck.  You would have to find a 3RCA/Component to Audio+DVI-D/VGA cable.  The problem is the Wii outputs both Video and Audio, your monitor only accepts video input.  Much easier to purchase a cheap tv at this point, your looking at 1/3 of the price for a cable/converter that might work.

Comment: I've known about the possibility to use a converter but wanted to see if there were any other options. I can already play the wii fine on a TV this was just about changing the location for gaming, so i will not invest in a converter that might not even work. Thanks for the answer now i don't have to search anymore :)

Comment: @Jkguitar - Your only option is a converter.  If you were talking about an XBOX 360 or PS3 then it would be a different story.  The Wii only supports 3-RCA(RYW) or Component(RYW-BX).  I forgot the last color...